# Eclipse Building Entire Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting erratic behavior from Eclipse (**3.7.0**) all of the sudden... this never used to happen, and as far as I can tell I haven't done anything or changed any settings that would incur this kind of behavior.

Every time I want to run a Java application (as a saved Run Configuration), I now need to `Project >> Clean` the project first. Otherwise, Eclipse will run the application from a "cached" state (whatever the code looked like the last time I cleaned it).

But, every time I clean the project, it attempts to build my entire workspace. This process takes about 2 minutes.

So every time I want to tweak some code and run my app, I need to clean it (**why?!?!**) and then wait for Eclipse to build every other open project in my workspace...again, **why?!?!**

This has been happening for about a week now, with no obvious system-level changes on my part. I have tried restarting both Eclipse and my machine to see if it was a temporary "hiccup", but it seems to be the new default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have checked the option *Build Automatically* under the Project menu. On the other hand, be aware that, by default, the *clean* option (under *Project* menu) tries to clean all the projects in the workspace. You will have to move the radio button to the option *Clean Projects selected bellow* in order to clean a subset of the projects contained in your workspace